# Story where people are transformed into alternate versions of themselves

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the author and title of a story where a process is used to transform people into their alter egos. All I remember is a bag lady turned into a sort of Amazon warrior, and a rich gangster turned into a flying elf-like creature. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I *think* this story was written in either the 1970s or possibly the 1980s.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: The more information you can provide about the story (and when/where you read it), the more likely it is that someone can identify it for you. We recommend that you look at our Guide: [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see what info you can add to this question.

Comment: Any story that involves bodily transformations of this nature to a significant extent makes me think of Jack L Chalker; all of his work involves some sort of bodily transformation (almost always of a fantastical nature, though at least one book limited it to a sort of amputation). That said, the specifics don't remind me of any of his stuff immediately.

Comment: Novel or short story?

Comment: It was a short story or novelette

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67162/a-group-of-people-willingly-transform-into-various-creatures-using-a-serum-of-so/243873 where someone is looking for the novel that the short story was expanded into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this story. It is called 'Jean Sandwich, the Sponsor, and I' by Ian Watson, and appeared in UNIVERSE 11 in 1981, edited by Terry Carr.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to tell us what this is, you should be able to accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: And, while this is a self-answer, can you explain how it matches?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. How it matches what?

Comment: @SteveH how it matches what you remembered, for instance by providing quotes, etc :)

Comment: FWIW, I looked this one up, and it does match. I could have sworn I copy-pasted quotes, but apparently not.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=rok1AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&lpg=PT49&dq=%22Jean+Sandwich,+the+Sponsor,+and+I%22&source=bl&ots=s7Z2xtTnUG&sig=ACfU3U1LXQJDXXwXS1v_sgv_tsSk_pWLIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCzdakz-vhAhUN01kKHVEnDqYQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Jean%20Sandwich%2C%20the%20Sponsor%2C%20and%20I%22&f=false has several pages of it.